# Maximum trace of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the maximum trace of $AB$. Where matrix $B$ is matrix with only two entries with value of 1, and matrix $A$ is matrix with entries of 3, and both $A$ and $B$ are square matrices.

example of matrix A

$\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 1\\ 
  2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

My attempt: the maximum trace will occur if all the ones element in $B$ were in the diagona, so there's two non zero entries in the diagonal. Make the corrospounding element in A to be 3. Thus the maximum tr($AB$)=6.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "matrix with entries of $3$"

Comment: entry with the value of 3

Comment: That is not clearer. I guess you're trying to say that $B$ is a matrix with two entries equal to $1$ and the rest equal to $0$, and $A$ is a matrix with entries at most equal to $3$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes sorry for my word not being clear

Comment: In that case, you have reached the correct conclusion: the maximum is indeed $6$. However, this maximum can be attained with **any** matrix $B$ with two entries equal to $1$.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated